# How can I set stackFromBottom in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

How can I set `stackFromBottom(boolean)` from ListView in RecyclerView? I need the first element in the list to be last element in the view.

For example, I have a list with 10 elements. On top of the view, I have an element with index 9, and at the bottom of the view I have an element with index 0. After I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` new elements are added to the bottom of the view.

In ListView, I use the setStackFromBottom method. Does RecyclerView have alternatives for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setReverseLayout(Boolean) method from RecyclerView.LinearLayoutManager - it's my choice.
setStackFromEnd(boolean) method was added for support with ListView

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but I think this could be a method you are looking for: [setStackFromEnd(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)) from `RecyclerView.LinearLayoutManager`.